# Cauchy Formula for $\oint \frac {\cos z}{z^3} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Q: compute integral

$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac {\cos z}{z^3} dz$$

A: I let $f(z)=\frac {\cos z}{z^3}$

$f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-0)}dz$

$f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{\cos (z=0)}{(z=0)^2}$

Now I'm stuck. I think I have to expand ${\cos z}$, but is it legal to do right before setting ${z=0}$, or do I have to expand it when it is still in the integral?

Answer (score 4):

[Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) is

$$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\,dz$$

Here, we have $f(z)=\cos z$, $z_0=0$ and $n=2$.  Therefore, we have

$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\cos z}{z^{3}}\,dz=\pi i\left.\frac{d^2\cos z}{dz^2}\right|_{z=0}=-\pi i$$